# Javascript - convert array to stringify format

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, stringify

I have this array:

```
   array =  [
    {
        "name": "name",
        "value": "Olá"
    },
    {
        "name": "age",
        "value": "23"
    },
    {
        "name": "isVisible",
        "value": "1"
    }
]
```

And i need to convert it to this stringified format:

```
"{\"name\":\"Olá\",\"age\":123,\"isVisible\":true}"
```

I have made several attempts without luck.

My last attempt was this one:

```
array = array.map((p) => {
          return Object.values(p).join(':').replace(/\[/g, '{').replace(/]/g, '}').toString();
        }),
```

Any solutions?

Comment: [sometimes reading the doc can be useful...  `JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply make a empty object, iterate over your array to populate that object, then `JSON.stringify(obj)` to get your result.

Like this:-

```
var obj = {};
array =  [
    {
        "name": "name",
        "value": "Olá"
    },
    {
        "name": "age",
        "value": "23"
    },
    {
        "name": "isVisible",
        "value": "1"
    }
]

for(let i of array) {
    obj[i.name] = i.value;
}

const str = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log(str);
/*
output : "{\"name\":\"Olá\",\"age\":123,\"isVisible\":true}"
*/
```

Comment: Thank you. You pointed me in the right direction.
I have transformed you for loop in a map and iterate over it.